# How to get POST and create message on Django using DetailView

Tags: python, django, detailview

I have Post model and Message model.

I want to get POST, create message on one post and preview it.

I have `ValueError` `Cannot assign "<bound method PostDetailView.post of <blog.views.PostDetailView object at 0x7fa9a370b8>>": "Message.post" must be a "Post" instance.` at `body = request.POST.get('body')`

How can I do this?

[All my code](https://github.com/igor-bond16/django_blog/tree/main/julia_blog)

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})


class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body[0:50]
```

views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        message = Message(
            user = request.user,
            post = self.post,
            body = request.POST.get('body')
        )
        message.save()
        return super(PostDetailView,self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
 path('post/<int:pk>',PostDetailView.as_view(),name='post-detail')
]
```

Comment: you have to pass a `post_id` to the url parameter and after that you can pass it to the message by doing something like this `message = Message.objects.create(user=request.user,post_id=post_id,body=request.POST.get('body'))` you are getting this error because of this `post = self.post` what are you calling `self.post` ?

Comment: ```self.post``` i means the post which message sended.

Comment: what is your url ?

Comment: I added my urls.py. I could get post_id by post_id = self.kwargs.get('pk') . Still I got an error ```IntegrityError 
NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_message.body``` at ```body = request.POST.get('body')```

Comment: My input tag which name='body' wasn't closed . I fixed it and message were successfully saved on data base, however i got another error, ```'super' object has no attribute 'post```. how should i fix this part?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your url has the `post_id` parameter, as in `https://example.com/?post_id=1`:

```
def get_post(post_id):
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        raise ValidationError(f"Post model with id {post_id} was not found.")

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        message = Message(
            user = request.user,
            post = self.get_post(kwargs.get('pk')),
            body = request.POST.get('body')
        )
        message.save()
        return super(PostDetailView,self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This should get you going. I strongly recommend setting up a serializer to validate your query parameters though.

```
class ParamValidationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    post_id = serializers.IntegerField()
```

Then change your post function to:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = ParamValidationSerializer(data={'post_id': kwargs.get('pk')})
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    message = Message(
        user = request.user,
        post = self.get_post(serializer.data.get('post_id')),
        body = request.POST.get('body')
    )
    message.save()
    return super(PostDetailView,self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I tried what you said and got an error at ```serializer = ParamValidationSerializer(data=request.query_params)```                                             ```'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'query_params'```

Comment: It's probbly because you are probably using only django and not django rest framework. You can change `request.query_params` to `request.GET` and it should work all the same.

Comment: I changet to request.GET and got another error, ```ValidationError
{'post_id': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}```

Comment: It's because your url doesn't have a `post_id` parameter like this: `https://example.com/?post_id=1`. What is the url?

Comment: this is my urls.py ```urlpatterns = [
 path('post/<int:pk>',PostDetailView.as_view(),name='post-detail')
]```

Comment: Okay, I have edited my response accordingly. Please try with the updated code

Comment: then i got another error ```get_post() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given```